# How to use prefetch_related in a ManyToMany relation using pk selected

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, python-3.6, django-class-based-views

How can I display the Category : many to many relation the movie belongs to in the detail page based on the pk selected on the List Page. I am looking for a way to accomplish this using prefetch_related i possible. Any other way is fine too.

models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    movie = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='categories')
```

views.py

```
class MovieListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movies'
    template_name = 'snippets/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Movie.objects.all()

class MovieDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'snippets/detail.html'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your get_context_data method is pointless. The DetailView already gets the object for you, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the the `queryset` of your `DetailView` to:

```
class MovieDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    queryset = Movie.objects.prefetch_related('categories')
    template_name = 'snippets/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'movie_name'
```

You do not need to do the filtering here, nor set the `get_context_data`. You can specify the name of the object with the `context_object_name` attribute, and a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) will automatically filter on the primary key given the url contains a `pk` parameter (as well as on the `slug` given the url contains a `slug` parameter). The [documentation on **`get_object`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) says:

> Returns the single object that this view will display. If `queryset`
>   is provided, that `queryset` will be used as the source of objects;
>   otherwise, `get_queryset()` will be used. `get_object()` looks for a
>   `pk_url_kwarg` argument in the arguments to the view; if this argument
>   is found, this method **performs a primary-key based lookup using that
>   value**. If this argument is not found, it looks for a
>   `slug_url_kwarg` argument, and performs a slug lookup using the
>   `slug_field`.
>
> When `query_pk_and_slug` is `True`, `get_object()` will perform its
>   lookup using both the primary key and the slug.

The name `movie_name` is however a bit "misleading" since one might expect that this deals with a name (a `str`ing), whereas this is a `Movie` object. Perhaps it is better to set the `context_object_name` to `'movie'` instead.

Note hwever that a `.prefetch_related` will still require an extra query to fetch the related categories into memory. So using `movie.categories` in the view, will result in the same number of queries.

In the template, you can for example render the `movie` with the categories like:

```
{{ movie }}; categories:
{% for category in movie.categories.all %}
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you.what i am trying to achieve is to display the name of the category the movie belongs to, along with the name of the movie. Your answer only display the name of the movie.Can you help please?

Comment: @CurtisBanks: in the template, you iterate over the categories, like `{% for category in movie_name %}{{ category }}{% endfor %}` (please rename to `movie`).